# Artemis ActiveMQ broker.xml wildcard-addresses configuration reference

Tags: microservices, activemq-artemis, messagebroker

I'm currently configuring an Artemis ActiveMQ Broker and need to change the default ''wildcard-addresses''. So I found the ''wildcard-addresses'' tag, but I didn't find the information I need, so I have two questions:

1. I want to set routing-enabled to true, but just for the tag ''any-words'' and disable the ''single-word'' tag (or just want to know if this is even possible).
2. I didn't find the answer in the official documentation, so I'm wondering if someone found a good reference which explains the different tags for the ''wildcard-addresses'' configuration, which is in the style of the ''[Configuration Reference](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuration-index.html)'', but includes a section about ''wildcard-addresses''.

What I've found so far but does not satisfy me:

- [Wildcard-syntax](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html)
- [Routing Messages with wildcards](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-routing.html)
- [Configuration reference](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuration-index.html)

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to disable certain match types (i.e. single word or any words), and it's not clear why one would want to.

The `wildcard-addresses` block is for enabling/disabling wild-card routing and for customizing the wild-card syntax.

Here's the basics (as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html)):

- A wildcard expression contains *words* delimited by the character defined by `delimiter` (i.e. `.` by default).
- The character defined by `any-words` (i.e. `#` by default) means "match any sequence of zero or more words."
- The character defined by `single-word` (i.e. `*` by default) means "match a single word."